# Java Eclipse multiline/list property in PropertyView

Tags: java, eclipse, list, view, properties

I have a `TreeViewer` with Objects which I want to show information in the default `PropertiesView` in Eclipse. I created an AdapterFactory which implements the `IAdapterFactory` Interface with the Override method:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterType)
{
    if(adapterType == IPropertySource.class && adaptableObject instanceof UATreeNode)
    {
        return new UATreeNodeAdapter((UATreeNode) adaptableObject);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I created an adapter which implements the `IPropertySource` Interface with my own PropertyDescriptors, for example:

```
public static final String OBJECT_ID_VALUE = "Obj.value";
private static final String OBJECT_LABEL_VALUE = "Value";
private static final String CATEGORY_VALUE = "Value";

protected PropertyDescriptor objectAccessLevelDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(OBJECT_ID_VALUE, OBJECT_LABEL_VALUE);

@Override
public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors()
{
    objectValueDescriptor.setCategory(CATEGORY_VALUE);
    return new IPropertyDescriptor[] { objectValueDescriptor };
}

@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(Object id)
{
    if(id.equals(OBJECT_ID_VALUE))
        return uaTreeNode.getValue();
}
```

Some of those properties should display a list of Strings,

```
Value
---String 1
---String 2
---String 3
```

[Example how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUByw.png)

The first occurance of "Value" is the category I set, but the second occurance should already display the actual value of the list I provide.

The problem is, the list is dynamical and can differ between my TreeNodes.
My question now, is there a way to do that and how can I achive what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `getPropertyValue` method returns an object that implements or adapts to `IPropertySource` then the property descriptors from that property source will be used to create child nodes.

So in your example you would need a property source returning three descriptors for the three strings.

Comment: Ok, the part with the child nodes work for me now, but how can I achive that I dynamically set a number of descriptors? I don´t know the exact length of my list.

Comment: You will have to create a property source object that has the correct number of descriptors when getPropertyValue for the object is called.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but here is what I did:

I created a new class which also implements the `IPropertySource` Interface:

```
public class UATreeNodeValue implements IPropertySource
{
    public static final String OBJECT_ID_STARTTIME = "Obj.startTime";
    public static final String OBJECT_ID_CURRENTTIME = "Obj.currentTime";
    public static final String OBJECT_ID_STATE = "Obj.state";

    private static final String OBJECT_LABEL_STARTTIME = "StartTime";
    private static final String OBJECT_LABEL_CURRENTTIME = "CurrentTime";
    private static final String OBJECT_LABEL_STATE = "State";


    String size = "";
    String objectType = "";
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected PropertyDescriptor descriptor;

    protected PropertyDescriptor objectStartTimeDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(
            OBJECT_ID_STARTTIME, OBJECT_LABEL_STARTTIME);
    protected PropertyDescriptor objectCurrentTimeDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(
            OBJECT_ID_CURRENTTIME, OBJECT_LABEL_CURRENTTIME);
    protected PropertyDescriptor objectStateDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(
            OBJECT_ID_STATE, OBJECT_LABEL_STATE);

    public UATreeNodeValue()
    {

    }

    public void addValues(String value)
    {
        arrayList.add(value);
    }

    public void setObjectType(String string)
    {
        objectType = string;
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors()
    {
        IPropertyDescriptor[] iPropertyDescriptor = new IPropertyDescriptor[arrayList.size()];
        if(objectType.equals("ServerStatusDataType"))
        {
            return new IPropertyDescriptor[] { objectStartTimeDescriptor, objectCurrentTimeDescriptor,
                    objectStateDescriptor };
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                size = "[" + i + "]";
                iPropertyDescriptor[i] = new PropertyDescriptor("obj." + "[" + i + "]", size);
            }
            return iPropertyDescriptor;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPropertyValue(Object id)
    {
        if(objectType.equals("ServerStatusDataType"))
        {
            if(id.equals(OBJECT_ID_STARTTIME))
                return arrayList.get(0);
            if(id.equals(OBJECT_ID_CURRENTTIME))
                return arrayList.get(1);
            if(id.equals(OBJECT_ID_STATE))
                return arrayList.get(2);  
        }
        else
        {
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 0 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(0);
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 1 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(1);
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 2 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(2);
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 3 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(3);
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 4 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(4);
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 5 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(5);
            if(id.equals("obj." + "[" + 6 + "]"))
                return arrayList.get(6);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> NOTE: I removed some part for simplification here.

For special cases I implemented the name of the property but in all other cases, it is just showing the number, for example [1], as the name.

In my adapter class I mentioned in my question above, I just giving back the value:

UATreeNodeAdapter class which also implements the `IPropertySource` Interface:

```
@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(Object id)
{
    if(id.equals(OBJECT_ID_VALUE))
        return uaTreeNode.getValue();
    return null;
}
```

UATreeNode class:

```
public class UATreeNode
{
    private UATreeNodeValue value = null;   

    public UATreeNodeValue getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(UATreeNodeValue value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I hope I can help someone who has similar proplems.
Thanks to greg-449 for help.